# How to listen for nested childChanged events in firebase?

Tags: swift, database, firebase

I have the following code;

```
newHandle = jobsRef.observe(.childChanged, with: { (jobSnapshot) in
        print(jobSnapshot)
        print(jobSnapshot.ref)
        print("end")
        self.childHandle = jobSnapshot.ref.observe(.childChanged, with: { (childSnapshot) in
            print("hello")
            print(childSnapshot)
        })
    })
```

My Databse looks like the following;

```
AllJobs
    JobID
        Name
        Description
```

JobsRef points to AllJobs, and the first 3 print statements get called when I change Name for instance. But I want the second to get called When I change name because I want to know if name was changed or description. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can attach tow listeners for name and description

```
jobsRef.observe(.childChanged, with: 
{ 
    (jobSnapshot) in
    // print(jobSnapshot)
    // print(jobSnapshot.ref)
    // print("end")
    jobSnapshot.ref..child("name").observe(.childChanged, with: { (childSnapshot) in
        print("name changed")
        print(childSnapshot)
    });

    jobSnapshot.ref.child("description").observe(.childChanged, with: { (childSnapshot) in
        print("description changed")
        print(childSnapshot)
    });

});
```

but keep in mind this will generate listeners for every job you observe which I think i is bad idea

---

**NOTE :** I used lower case names for child names (name , description) you need to change these if they are different

Comment: so what would be the efficient way of adding listeners?

Comment: you need to listen to one entry not the whole list